# Use Oracle for ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: oracle, asp.net-membership

I have a web site in asp.net (web forms not MVC) with .NET framework 4.6.1 with standard Microsoft authentication on SQL Server:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SecuritySqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="SecuritySqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ManageUsers" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             applicationName="SecurityTutorials" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" 
             defaultProvider="SecuritySqlRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="SecuritySqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"  
             applicationName="SecurityTutorials" 
             connectionStringName="ManageUsers" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now we've changed from Microsoft to Oracle and I need to adapt provider to manage membership.

I am unable to find anything good to make this work.

I found this [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/rudysetyo/asp-net-membership-and-role-provider-using-oracle-database-part-1) but it is incomplete.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved on my own way.

View at

[GitHub](https://github.com/francogiacobbi/Oracle-Providers-for-ASP.NET-Membership-and-Roles)